# Get x:Uid propertry of TextBlock in Metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Is there any way to get `x:uid` property of control in metro apps.

```
            <Button x:Name="ViewPanelButton" 
                    Grid.Column="3" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    x:Uid="s_View" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                    Margin="5,0,0,5" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MainPageButtonStyle}" 
                    Click="ViewPanelButton_Click" 
                    Height="22" 
                    Width="Auto" />
```

I want to get this x:Uid property from code behind. It is property in WPF but not in metro. Is there any way to get this property in metro apps ?

Comment: Hmm, it's not exposed. Never thought about it until now. Sheesh. I would be interested into why you want to access this.

Comment: Because i need it for localization when user want to change app language not system language as already render pages not change their text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regret, I have confirmed with the platform team that you cannot do this (yet).

You can, however, manually set the default language.

```
public void Setup()
{
    var r = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
    r.QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValues_MapChanged;
}

public void Cleanup()
{
    var r = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
    r.QualifierValues.MapChanged -= QualifierValues_MapChanged;
}

void QualifierValues_MapChanged(Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableMap<string, string> sender, Windows.Foundation.Collections.IMapChangedEventArgs<string> @event)
{
    // you can fetch the default, and test if you need change
    string d;
    var m = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues;
    if (!m.TryGetValue("Language", out d))
        return;

    // you can set your own or use the first (default)
    var l = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages.First();
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = l;
}
```

Best of luck!