# Windows 8.1 app - assigning UID to Windows.UI.XAML.Controls.Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I'm creating Windows.UI.XAML.Controls.Button dynamically in code. 
I'd like to associate each button with a GUID.

If I was to create this in XAML, it would look something like (ignoring the bad Uid):

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" x:Uid="xyz123-Button"/>
```

In Windows.Controls.Button there is a property that allows me to do something like:

```
newButton.Uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

But in the Windows.UI.XAML.Controls.Button there is no property that i can see that would allow me to assign a unique identifier.

**Question**: How would I add the "x:Uid" to the control?  Is there a way to set and get it programatically?

thanks.

Comment: After some more clicking ... I see that it has a property "Name".  I think this may work although I do prefer the Uid if possible.

Comment: The property "Name" is not really intended for that (though it would work). `Name` when set in XAML will automatically create a variable in the autogenerated code for that page.

Comment: If you want to use something custom try using the `Tag` attribute

Comment: **Solution:** use XAML instead. There's no reason to instantiate UI elements in procedural code in XAML based technologies.

Comment: It is not possible for Windows Store App. Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349220/get-xuid-propertry-of-textblock-in-metro

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my code so i don't have a say on how to go forward with this.  Thanks Omada and HighCore.  I'll use the Tag attribute for now.